# Error building wxWidgets program with CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I want to build some program with CodeBlocks and wxWidgets, but every time i launch something i get an error:

```
||=== Build: Release in 555 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include||No such file or directory|
Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu||No such file or directory|
||preprocessing failed.|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

But I DO see those directories in `C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include`  and  `C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu`
I've done everything like in this video:[How to build wxWidget and use on Code::Blocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmobZRIlBMU)
and official wiki - but nothing works. When the library was compiling, there was no errors.
Here is full build log:

```
-------------- Build: Release in 666 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -O2 -std=gnu++11 -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu" -c D:\Programs\C\Vis\666\wx_pch.h -o wx_pch.h.gch\Release_wx_pch_h_gch
g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -O2 -std=gnu++11 -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu" -c D:\Programs\C\Vis\666\_66App.cpp -o obj\Release\_66App.o
g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -O2 -std=gnu++11 -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu" -c D:\Programs\C\Vis\666\_66Main.cpp -o obj\Release\_66Main.o
windres.exe -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu"  -J rc -O coff -i D:\Programs\C\Vis\666\resource.rc -o obj\Release\resource.res
g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll" -o bin\Release\666.exe obj\Release\_66App.o obj\Release\_66Main.o  obj\Release\resource.res -s -mthreads  -lwxmsw30u -mwindows
gcc: error: Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu: No such file or directory
windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 7 second(s))
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are build errors, so you cannot build your app. The problem seems to be that folders like `Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include` cannot be found (notice the missing `C:\Program`?). Try adding quotes around dir names.

Comment: I added full build log, and i don't see there any missing dir names

Comment: `gcc: error: Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include: No such file or directory`, you have it right there. Did you try to enclose dirs in quotes?

Comment: They are in quotes, aren't they? `windres.exe -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-3.0.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu"  -J rc -O coff -i D:\Programs\C\Vis\666\resource.rc -o obj\Release\resource.res`   Or what quotes do you mean?

Comment: In the video you linked, at 3:50 and onward, the dirs there are not enclosed in quotes (but they also do not contain spaces). So, in C::B settings, in the same places shown in the video, do you have the dirs enclosed in quotes already?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're a missing quotes around the compiler options, so your `-IC:/Program Files/wxWidgets...` gets broken into `-IC:/Program` and `Files/wxWidgets...`, which is what you see.

The immediate solution would be to just add the quotes in the same place where you entered this path.

In the future, I'd strongly recommend not using directories with spaces in them for anything programming-related. It should work, of course, with sufficiently careful use of quotes but it's just some extra pain to deal with and nobody needs that.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice @catalin's answer when I wrote this one. It's basically the same thing, so this one is mostly redundant but maybe worth leaving just for the advice to avoid paths with spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, putting dirs in quotes didn't help, but moving whole wx directory to `C:\` did.